# Geoserver Performance Bootleneck in Docker - Response Time is very high

Tags: geoserver, performance, tomcat, docker

I am using GeoServer 2.20.4 & Tomcat9.0.62 version in live environment with Docker. Sometimes I have performance issues. I'm investigating the reason for this.

The server has 24gb RAM. It can use 22.46 GB RAM in GeoServer.
But "Total Memory : 17000MB" appears in JVM field in Tomcat.

My question is; Could a bottleneck occur when the JVM reaches about 17gb? Am I limited to 17gb RAM? Do I need to change this value or can GeoServer use 22.46gb RAM?

I periodically check the manager/status page in Tomcat with selenium. I generate an alarm when there is a response time of more than 10 seconds. The attached alarm values are available.

I think the problem is due to the amount of RAM on the server not being used efficiently, but I'm not sure.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxCv3.jpg has contained GeoServer & Tomcat & Tomcat when alarmed

Comment: So you don't think that the operating system should use any RAM at all? If you want the app to use more RAM, why not add more RAM?

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply

First of all, we increased the ram from 12gb to 24gb. However, our problem persists.
Actually my question is: why does jvm show "Total Memory 17000MB"? Can this value be increased statically? Or does the capacity increase dynamically for jvm?

Comment: it depends on what sort of data you are serving - rasters need more memory than vectors, badly prepared data is usually more of a problem than the amount of memory being used. You are probably best acquiring commercial support to help solve your problem